# What's the difference between these "break" verbs: 깨다/깨지다/깨뜨리다?

Tags: vocabulary

깨다, 깨지다, and 깨뜨리다 come up as "break" when looked up. What's the difference, how are they used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences is in the [transitiveness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/transitiveness) of the words.

- 깨뜨리다/깨다 is *transitive* and takes an object. The subject breaks the object. [깨뜨리다 is an emphasized version of 깨다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6183000)

  - Someone *broke* something.
  - I *broke* the glass.
  - The kids will break my window.
- 깨지다 is *intransitive* and does not take an object. The subject becomes broken.

  - Something was broken by someone. (Something broke)
  - The glass was broken by me. (The glass broke)
  - The window will break because of the kids. (The window will be broken by the kids.)

This ~지다/~뜨리다 isn't a universal grammar rule, but the pattern does apply to a few other words, like 넘어지다 and 미끄러지다:

- 넘어지다 => To fall over.
- 넘어뜨리다 => To cause to fall over (push something over).
- 미끄러지다 => To slip and fall.
- 미끄러뜨리다 => To cause to slip and fall.

Comment: Wouldn't 깨다 also be a transitive form of "to break"? If not, what would be the difference between 깨다 and 깨뜨리다?

Comment: @blimpy 깨뜨리다 [is an emphasized version of 깨다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=6183000). In hindsight, feels like I should edit that information in for clarity, thanks!